# Is it a bug or an error from my side with ionic 4 and HTTP/S (GET, POST)

Tags: typescript, http, https, request, ionic4

I want to call a REST API service in my Ionic 4 app, but every HTTP module from Ionic or Angular doesn't work with it. It throws this error  every time:

> [ng] src/services/Service.ts(5,24): error TS2307: Cannot find module
>   'https'. [ng] src/services/Service.ts(29,11): error TS2580: Cannot
>   find name 'process'. Do you need to install type definitions for node?
>   Try `npm i @types/node`.

The second error with @types/node, comes every time but this module work.

Here is my code:

```js
import * as forge from 'node-forge';
import * as https from 'https';

export class Service
{

  constructor(){}

//Convert an normal text in a SHA1 text
//here i use the module node-forge and it work
  textToSha1(text)
  {
    var md = forge.md.sha1.create();
    md.update(text);
    return md.digest().toHex();
  }


//In this function i call a restApi Service with https, in an nodeJs test work it 
//init include the https header parameter (url, port, path, etc...)
  getDataFromRestApi( init )
  {
    https.get(init, (res) => {
      console.log('statusCode:', res.statusCode);
      console.log('headers:', res.headers);

      res.on('data', (d) => {
          process.stdout.write(d);
      });
    }).on('error', (e) => {
      console.error(e);
    });
  }

  isNotEmpty(obj)
  {
    return (obj != null && obj != undefined && obj != '');
  }
}
```

My current dev system is:

> Ionic:
>        Ionic CLI                     : 5.1.0 (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/ionic)    Ionic Framework               :
>   @ionic/angular 4.5.0    @angular-devkit/build-angular : 0.13.9
>   @angular-devkit/schematics    : 7.3.9    @angular/cli
>   : 7.3.9    @ionic/angular-toolkit        : 1.5.1   Cordova:
>        Cordova CLI       : 9.0.0 (cordova-lib@9.0.1)    Cordova Platforms : none    Cordova Plugins   : no whitelisted plugins (1
>   plugins total)   Utility:
>        cordova-res : not installed    native-run  : not installed   System:
>        NodeJS : v10.15.3 (/usr/local/bin/node)    npm    : 6.9.0    OS     : macOS Mojave    Xcode  : Xcode 10.2.1 Build version 10E1001

Has anyone an idea what is wrong here?

Comment: Looks like you're trying to use Node (server-side) libraries from Ionic/Angular (client-side) code. That rarely works, but may, depending on how you have your project set up. Typically, in Angular anyway, one uses HttpClient to make HTTPS requests to a server.

Comment: I have testit with nodejs and later with this: https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/http and this: https://ionicacademy.com/http-calls-ionic/ but the error is the same.

Comment: If you're using either of those, you have no need for referencing `process` or `https`, so I don't see how you could be getting the same error...

Comment: mhh can not restore the error now with @ionic-native/http